# solder mask clearance

Tags: pcb-fabrication, solder-mask

[image]

The current soldermask clearance in GERBER is 3 mils.
Will PCB house reduce it base on their capabilities?

I'm a fresh DFM engineer in an EMS company. Soldermask analysis is a part of DFM, changes of soldermask will affect DFM analysis.

I am curious about what changes will PCB houses make besides soldermask?

Thanks!

Comment: Hm.. why don't you ask your fabhouse? AFAIK fab houses won't modify files, although they might notify you that your file is unfit for what they can achieve.

Comment: Do you want them to the soldermask clearance?  What's your actual concern, ultimately?

Comment: I'm a fresh DFM engineer in an EMS company. Soldermask analysis is a part of DFM, changes of soldermask will affect DFM analysis.

Comment: 3 mil is a fairly tight tolerance. More likely they'd want to increase it, rather than decrease it to improve manufacturability.

Comment: What have you found in your [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=solder+mask+clearance+guide&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixt_mB6-nPAhWIv1QKHYDIDPcQvwUIGygA)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "solder mask opening" in a footprint?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254886/what-is-a-solder-mask-opening-in-a-footprint)

Answer (score 1):

Any decent PCB manufacturer will never modify your files without asking you first.

In their website you should find the criteria that your PCB must fit. This will vary between manufacturers depending on their capabilities.

If you meet their criteria and the PCB comes with a different clearence than what you have on your gerber file, it will simply be because of the tolerance.

Comment: I heard that PCB manufacturers change gerbers all the time to make the boards more manufacturable on their end.

Comment: Some shops will change the gerbers to improve manufacturability, but they'll ask the customer first. The ones I work with call this "engineering query" or "EQ".